# Why overlapping operator overloads don't cause a run-time exception

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

It's interesting to see that having two matching operator overloads defined in different types, it is the order of their declaration that decides which overload will be used.

Having:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public static Bar operator +(Foo f, Bar b) => new Bar() { Test = "plus_op_from_Bar" };
}
public class Foo
{
    public static Bar operator +(Foo f, Bar b) => new Bar() { Test = "plus_op_from_Foo" };
}
```

`new Foo() + new Bar()` results in Test == "plus_op_from_Bar".

Switch the order of the classes and you get:

`new Foo() + new Bar()` resulting in Test == "plus_op_from_Foo".

I guess it would be not efficient to detect this during compilation but perhaps run-time exception would be nice to inform programmer about the case?

I didn't find this behaviour mentioned in C# spec - did I miss it?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  What compiler version are you using?  Copying this code into a console application, I am getting CS0034, Operator is ambiguous.

Comment: And the C# Spec [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution) it should fail: "If overload resolution fails to select a single best operator, a binding-time error occurs."

Comment: Overload resolution applies to overloaded operators, exactly the same way it does any other methods. In your example, the overload that is "closer" is selected as being "better". See e.g. marked duplicate.

Comment: @Peter "distance in lines of code" is not part of the "betterness", as far as I know.

Comment: ohhh, I only tested in C# interactive :O my fault, sorry and thank you :)

Comment: Well, that explains it.  The last one in wins.

Comment: @CodeCaster: it doesn't normally. But then normally you'd get an "ambiguous" error. In the extant example, "distance" does in fact apply (or rather, "most recent").